# Rails 3 form uses "edit" instead of "update" when the form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, methods, form-for

I have a problem with my form in Rails 3. The forms work if I create something, but if I try to update something, they fail. In this exmaple I tried to update the user settings, like name, mail etc. Here are the relevant code snippets:

Edit and Update from User_Controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @title = "Nutzerverwaltung"
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profil aktualisiert"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Then, there is the form:

```
%form.user_edit
  = form_for @user, :url => {:controller => "users", :action => "update"}, :html => { :method => :put } do |f|
    = render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object
    = render 'fields', :f => f
    .actions
      = f.submit "Update"
```

My terminal output when running the local WEBrick Server (some of the form labels have german names):

```
Started GET "/users/2/edit?utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=put&authenticity_token=R5LfeIAjpJOpH%2B0yMD8PLO24%2Fgcct0CCqXuzoLoVibs%3D&user%5Banrede%5D=&user%5Bname%5D=Johnny&user%5Bemail%5D=t.schneider%40mail.com&user%5Bpassword%5D=&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=&user%5Bplz%5D=&user%5Bort%5D=&user%5Bstrasse%5D=&commit=Update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-13 15:53:24 +0200
  Processing by UsersController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"R5LfeIAjpJOpH+0yMD8PLO24/gcct0CCqXuzoLoVibs=", "user"=>{"anrede"=>"", "name"=>"TESTer", "email"=>"t.schneider@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "plz"=>"", "ort"=>"", "strasse"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 2) LIMIT 1
Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.haml (2.2ms)
Rendered users/_fields.html.haml (7.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.haml (2.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_header.html.haml (3.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.haml (2.0ms)
Rendered users/edit.html.haml within layouts/application (33.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 118ms (Views: 36.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

And then there is my rake routes, which seems ok for me:

```
       users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
       users POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
        user PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
        user DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
    sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
 new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
     session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
       posts POST   /posts(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"posts"}
   edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
        post DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
        root        /(.:format)               {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"start"}
                    /(.:format)               {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"start"}
       start        /start(.:format)          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"start"}
     kontakt        /kontakt(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"kontakt"}
    tagebuch        /tagebuch(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"tagebuch"}
 hinzufuegen        /hinzufuegen(.:format)    {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"hinzufuegen"}
   bluefocus        /bluefocus(.:format)      {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"bluefocus"}
    seminare        /seminare(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"seminare"}
    angebote        /angebote(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"angebote"}
    specials        /specials(.:format)       {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"specials"}
        shop        /shop(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"shop"}
registrieren        /registrieren(.:format)   {:controller=>"users", :action=>"registrieren"}
       login        /login(.:format)          {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"login"}
      logout        /logout(.:format)         {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
                    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"edit"}
```

I know that this function of editing was working once, but i don't know what changed, so that it doesn't work anymore.

If you need anymore information just say a word.

Every help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `%form.user_edit` tag in your HAML, immediately before `form_for` which generates a form tag.  Since you are not specifying the url to submit the form to (in the form tag you manually create), it is probably posting by default to the current url (presumably, your user edit route).

Try removing the `%form.user_edit` and adding `:html => {:class => 'user_edit', :method => :put}` to your `form_for` call.

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks!!! I've been searching for the whole day and didn't see it. Just removed it and now it works perfect. Really man, thank you again! And again! And again! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `update_attributes` is returning False and causing your edit action to be rendered. What `attr_accessible` attributes exist on your user model?

Also: What validations exist?

Comment: the `attr_accessible` are `:name, :email :password, :password_confirmation` and i also validate the first three, but since the creation of the user works I don't think that the validations fail, because I just change numbers or letters, not the length or any other things. Besides that, there should also be an error, when something is wrong (at least there was when this method still workes).